# Reference counted structure exposing a POD interface

Tags: c++, reference-counting, binary-compatibility

I currently have a structure that declares a copy constructor, and a destructor, and keeps a reference count to a pimpl object. This allows me to pass this structure around by value. I need to refactor it because I want it to have a POD interface because it's part of a library that now needs to be used from code that uses an older C++ flavor.
Because of this, I have to remove both the copy constructor and the desctructor. I can't figure out how I can keep this nice "pass by value", multiple ownership mechanism after I have removed that. Shared pointers are not an option because the structure is used as parameter to the method of other classes that also need to be seen as POD from the perspective of the user of the library.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(const Foo&);
  const Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
  ~ Foo();
private:
  void* pimpl;
};

struct MainLibrary {
   void DoSomething(Foo param);
}
```

The user code now is like:

```
MainLibrary ml;
{
  Foo a;
  ml.doSomething(a);
}
```

at this point, the a variable can be kept for a long time inside the main library. For efficiency, the internals of Foo can't be deep copied each time, that's why the pimpl implementation keeps a reference counter that is incremented each time the instance of Foo is copied, decremented each time the instance of Foo is destroyed.

Comment: "am older C++ flavour" that doesn't support invoking your copy constructor, destructor?  How can that even be C++?  You should revisit that because what you ask amounts to "I can't keep track of these objects but I need some other object deleted when they're all done with" - without destructors, you can only try linking a garbage collector.

Comment: No, problem is that I am using C++11 throughout the library and it should be possible to link to it by using code compiled without the C++11 flags… if I have non POD types then I get name mangling errors when linking

Comment: That's a pretty big insight to leave out of your question.  In that case I'm sure  you could still use your current design using a bit of "glue" data and/or functions - perhaps make them extern "C" non-members so they can be called from either side, have the C++11 code register callbacks so the pre-C++11 side can find the functions it needs.  Also check your compiler docs to see if they offer any control of the name mangling differences....

Comment: sorry, I didn't get this. can you give me an example of the functions you talk about given the example code? thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much for a comment... something like below.  Client include foo03.h and their usage should remain unaffected.  Your C++11 implementation is invoked via a "C" layer.  You can find lots of examples if you search for "exposing C++ code to C" or similar....

foo03.h:

```
extern "C"
{
    void* foo_constructor();
    void* foo_constructor2(void* rhs);
    void foo_assign(void* lhs, void* rhs);
    void foo_destructor(void* p_this);
}

struct Foo {
    Foo() { p_ = foo_constructor(); }
    Foo(const Foo& rhs) { p_ = foo_constructor2(rhs.p_); }
    const Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) { foo_assign(p_, rhs.p_); return *this; }
    ~Foo() { foo_destructor(p_); }
  private:
    void* p_;
};
```

foo11.h:

```
// up to you whether you call this Foo (relying on mangling differences to avoid conflicts when
// linking with C++03 objects), FooImpl, put it in a namespace ala Impl::Foo etc..
struct FooImpl {
    FooImpl() { ... }
    FooImpl(const FooImpl&) { ... }
    const FooImpl& operator=(const FooImpl& rhs) { ... }
    ~FooImpl() { ... }
};

extern "C"
{
    void* foo_constructor() { return new FooImpl(); }
    void* foo_constructor2(void* rhs) { return new FooImpl(*(FooImpl*)rhs); }
    void foo_assign(void* lhs, void* rhs) { *(FooImpl*)lhs = *(FooImpl*)rhs; }
    void foo_destructor(void* p_this) { delete (FooImpl*)p_this; }
}
```

Comment: @AlexDarsonik You're welcome - hope it goes smoothly.

Comment: As far as I know plain C has no function overload (and there is no name mangling to distinguish them), so your two `foo_constructor`s will clash.